# I read that you cant leave Teams for core and non core scenarios

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

So I have an app on a website that loads in an iframe.  Is this allowed or not in app source and the teams design challenge.  I also read that you can have an exe launch.  Where would we store the exe so that it could launch?

Comment: Yes, You can load Iframe with in teams as tab. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/quickstarts/create-personal-tab-dotnet-core)?

Answer (score 0):

You can load Iframe with in teams as tab. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/quickstarts/create-personal-tab-dotnet-core)?